# Ошибка при обрезке tiff-файла

Tags: c#, изображения, crop

Эта тема является продолжением https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/574394/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE?noredirect=1#comment757642_574394

Есть tiff-файл который я хочу обрезать. Я пробовал сохранять его во всех форматах, однако при обрезке он съеживается в полоску. С любым другим jpeg файлом все работает, с tiff-нет. Вот пример файла для теста https://yadi.sk/i/Iqw3jv2wwQ3EV

```
public Bitmap CropImage(Image img)
    {
        // create a graphic path to hold the shape data
        GraphicsPath path = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
        var points = new Point[]
        {
            new Point(85, 1111), new Point(934, 1111), new Point(934, 952), new Point(1642, 952),
            new Point(1642, 2000), new Point(85, 2000), new Point(85, 1111)
        };
        GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
        gp.AddPolygon(points.ToArray());

        Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(2220, 2220);

        using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp1))
        {
            G.Clip = new System.Drawing.Region(gp);
            G.DrawImage(img, 0, 0);
            pictureBox.Image = bmp1;
            return bmp1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: По ссылке на ядиске ничего не найдено. Перезалейте файл. А так, думаю, нужно или `PixelFormat` или `Resolution` правильный задать.

Comment: Вы проверьте сначала, что у вас TIFF загружается правильно без обрезки. А то может оказаться что он у вас многостраничный или еще что-то, и в полоску съеживается не из-за обрезки. И разрешение у файла проверьте, потому что вы его в свой Bitmap грузите без указания размера, он может оказаться как больше, так и меньше нужного.